# Correlated alpha-stable processes with different alpha values

Tags: correlation, stochastic-processes

Can one define a pair of stochastic processes with independent alpha-stable increments and different alpha parameter (index of stability) values (e.g. a Brownian motion and a Cauchy or Levy process) which are correlated?

Comment: A possible solution consists of constructing the increments using a bivariate [copula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copula_%28probability_theory%29) (*e.g.* Gaussian) with $\alpha-$stable marginals with the desired parameters. Marginally, they will satisfy the assumptions you mention but the processes will be correlated if $\rho\neq 0$ in the case of a Gaussian copula.

Comment: You should write that up as an answer @Procrastinator. That's what I would do.

Comment: @Procrastinator Would this work with infinitesimal increments as well?

Comment: @quant_dev I am not sure if I follow your question. My point is to use a copula for inducing correlation between the processes. This is, assuming that [the increments](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%A9vy_process#Mathematical_Definition) $(X_t,Y_t)-(X_s,Y_s)$ follow the aforementioned bivariate distribution. Marginally the original assumptions are satisfied.

Comment: @Procrastinator I understand that. My question is, can I specify a copula linking infinitesimal increments $(X_{t+dt},T_{t+dt}) - (X_t,Y_y)$ and obtain a well-defined Levy process?

Comment: @quant_dev My point applies to the original construction of Levy processes, for any $s<t$. I think this construction will produce two well-defined and correlated processes but it would be good to fill all the details.

Comment: I think you will be interested in [this recent answer on MO](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/57808/correlated-brownian-motion-and-poisson-process/57898#57898).